# Integrating Twitter with sharekit 2.0

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, twitter-oauth, sharekit

I want to integrate shareKit 2.0 in my app. But I wanted only for the purpose of Twitter. 
I Followed the installation steps on sharkit wiki but ended with the error youTube SDK not found etc... 
I see lot of products in my app product folder(Fiker, youtube sdk, ect...)
As I only needed twitter,I deleted other folder except Twitter from services  folder. Please help me with the sharkit twitter Integration.

I want to update sharekit As i am facing oAuth_verifier issue in twitter with the old sharekit version.

**sharkit 2.0 source Code URL:** 
https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit

**Installations Steps URL:**
https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki

Answer (score 1):

May be you don't need ShareKit? If you just going to set up twitter share you can use ios integrated framework, here it is good [tutorial](http://ios.biomsoft.com/2012/02/05/using-the-twitter-framework-in-ios-5/).

Comment: My applications needs to take care of lower versions too so can not use twitter framework.

Answer (score 0):

New sharekit is very different from the old one, and you should not touch the code (delete anything) - the strongest reason is easy updating using git.

If you wish to use Twitter sharer only, check [granular install](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Granular-install)